# Scope of length() method

Tags: java

After doing

```
String delims = "[\n]";
String[] tokens = text.split(delims); //text is composed of one single word per line
```

I would need to know how many lines (via the number of components of the corresponding splitted string)

```
int k=tokens.length(); //does not work
```

Is there a method for doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `length` field:

```
  int k=tokens.length;
```

Because `tokens` is an array you need to use `length` field, but `length()` method it's for strings.